# AngularJS ngResource custom params passing two '&' to odata service

Tags: angularjs, odata, ngresource

I swear this was working before I upgraded ngResource to 1.3.11...

So my issue is that when I apply a custom filter param to my odata resource request, the filter appends an extra $ before it write the parameter.

```
http://myservice/odata/Data?&format=application%2Fjson&$filter=year(Date)+lt+2012
```

The above works just fine through fiddler and is the correct request.

I'm using ngResource to make the get request

```
data.factory('DataService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var odataUrl = 'http://myservice/odata/Data?&format=application%2Fjson'; 
    var d = $resource('', {
        filter: '@filter'
    }, {            
        queryByYear: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: odataUrl, isArray: false
        }
    });
    return d;

}]);
```

and controller function is as follows:

```
$scope.getByYear = function (op) {

        DataService.queryByYear({ filter: 'year(PublishedDate) ' + op }, function (data) {
            $scope.events = data;
        });
    };
```

For some reason the output of this request is as follows:

```
http://myservice/odata/Data?&format=application%2Fjson&$$filter=year(Date)+lt+2012
```

Notice the second and completely unnecessary & beside the filter param...

any thoughts?

Comment: Actually is has nothing to do with the version of ngResource. Looking into what changed in AngularJS and how they handle xhr.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into what was happening when converting my odata request to the proper format, I realized that I had added a third party angular-odata module that was preforming the conversion. The newer angularjs $http already handles this conversion. Doh!